# Next/js Background Image covers the title

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to optimize the app so that's why I have changed the classic  with  from Next/js. The problem now is the image covers the details. I have tried to solve the problem using z-index, but it doesn't work.

```
<div className="keen-slider h-screen w-screen" ref={sliderRef}>
        {plays.map(({ id, body, banner_image, union_member, title, slug }) => (
          <div
            key={id}
            className="z-10 keen-slider__slide bg-cover bg-no-repeat w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center max-w-screen-xl mx-auto"
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(15, 41, 55, 0.65), rgba(15, 41, 55, 0.65))`,
            }}
          >
            <Container className="z-0 w-full">
              <Image
                src={getMedia(banner_image)}
                alt={title}
                className="z-0 w-full object-cover"
                layout="fill"
              />{' '}
              <h1 className="z-10 text-secondary text-5xl lg:text-7xl">{title}</h1>
              <div className="z-20 text-white mt-5 sh1">{union_member?.title}</div>
              <div className="z-30 text-secondary mt-5 mb-16 text-xl font-light lg:w-3/4">
                <CustomMarkdown body={body} />
              </div>
              <Button to={`${Routes.WHATS_ON}/${slug}`}>Read More</Button>
            </Container>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

How it was with :

[image]

And know, those details and the button are behind the image.

Comment: Try making your `Container` component `relative`.

Comment: It displays the details but the gradient is not applied

Comment: Use the `:after` pseudo element on your Container to create an overlay instead of adding background in your wrapper.

Comment: Something like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/3PvXxCseRr